# Flutter - How to have arbitrary number of implicit animations

Tags: animation, dart, widget, flutter, state

I've made a widget that takes a list of `children`, and a `List<double>` of `gaps`, which displays the children with the respective gap between them. I've made it so passing a new list of `gaps` causes the widget to animate from the old gap to the new gaps (changing number of gaps not supported).

What's the best way to handle implicity animating the gaps?

This is the kind of behaviour I'm looking for: [image: example]
<sub>(source: [gfycat.com](https://thumbs.gfycat.com/QuerulousTintedBlacknorwegianelkhound-size_restricted.gif))</sub>

Comment: Stackoverflow is not about code-review. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199680/whats-acceptable-practice-for-stack-overflow-code-review-for-several-source-fil for more infos. You might want instead to make a question like "How to do X ?" and then add your own solution as answer. And see what others offer

Comment: Okay I'll change it a bit, thanks

Comment: Nice. Can you also add a gif of the desired visual behavior on the question ? :)

Comment: @RémiRousselet done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid unneeded repetition you can move the tween logic to a custom widget.

You can also fuse `List<Widget> children` with `List<double> gaps` with a custom `Gap` widget.

Ultimately you can keep using `ListView` via `separated` constructor and use our custom `Gap` as separators.

---

Taking all of this into consideration, in the end your `Gap` widget is simply an `AnimatedContainer` with a custom height:

```
class Gap extends StatelessWidget {
  final double gap;

  const Gap(this.gap, {Key key})
      : assert(gap >= .0),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
      curve: Curves.easeOut,
      height: gap,
    );
  }
}
```

And you can then use it using the following:

```
ListView.separated(
  itemCount: 42,
  addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return RaisedButton(onPressed: null, child: Text("Foo $index"));
  },
  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Gap(10.0);
  },
),
```

The `addAutomaticKeppAlives: true` here is used to ensure that items leaving then reappearing don't have their animation reset. But it is not a necessity.

Here's a full example with dynamically changing gap size:

[image]

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomeState createState() {
    return new HomeState();
  }
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final rand = Random.secure();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {});
            },
            child: Text("Reroll random gaps"),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.separated(
              addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
              itemCount: 42,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                print("Bar");
                return RaisedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Foo $index"));
              },
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                print("Foo $index");
                return Gap(rand.nextDouble() * 10.0);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! There's always an easy widget like that, trick is knowing what!

Comment: I like to think that in flutter, if you need more than 100 lines to do something then you did it wrong :p

Answer (score 1):

This was my solution, but my code is pretty messy. In particular, I'm not sure having a seperate list for the animations, tweens, controllers and curves (which is what I'm doing now) is the best way to do things. Also doing `List<int>.generate(widget.gaps.length, (i) => i).forEach` in the `build` function seems wrong, but the usual `for (var i; i<x; i++)` doesn't seem very dart-y either.

Is there a better way to handle these two issues?

```
class GappedList extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Widget> children;
  final List<double> gaps;
  GappedList({@required this.children, @required this.gaps}) :
    assert(children != null),
    assert(children.length > 0),
    assert(gaps != null),
    assert (gaps.length >= children.length - 1);
  @override
  GappedListState createState() {
    return new GappedListState();
  }
}

class GappedListState extends State<GappedList> with TickerProviderStateMixin{
  List<Animation> _animations = [];
  List<AnimationController> _controllers = [];
  List<CurvedAnimation> _curves = [];
  List<Tween<double>> _tweens;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tweens = widget.gaps.map((g) => Tween(
      begin: g ?? 0.0,
      end: g ?? 0.0,
    )).toList();
    _tweens.forEach((t) {
      _controllers.add(AnimationController(
        value: 1.0,
        vsync: this,
        duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
      ));
      _curves.add(CurvedAnimation(parent: _controllers.last, curve: Curves.ease));
      _animations.add(t.animate(_curves.last));
    });
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controllers.forEach((c) => c.dispose());
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(GappedList oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    assert(oldWidget.gaps.length == widget.gaps.length);
    List<Tween<double>> oldTweens = _tweens;
    List<int>.generate(widget.gaps.length, (i) => i).forEach(
      (i) {
        _tweens[i] = Tween<double>(
          begin: oldTweens[i].evaluate(_curves[i]),
          end: widget.gaps[i] ?? 0.0,
        );
        _animations[i] = _tweens[i].animate(_curves[i]);
        if (_tweens[i].begin != _tweens[i].end) {
          _controllers[i].forward(from: 0.0);
        }
      }
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> list = [];
    List<int>.generate(widget.children.length, (i) => i).forEach(
      (i) {
        list.add(widget.children[i]);
        if (widget.children[i] != widget.children.last) {
          list.add(
            AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: _animations[i],
              builder: (context, _) => ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints.tightForFinite(
                  height: _animations[i].value,
                ),
              ),
            )
          );
        }
      }
    );
    return ListView(
      primary: true,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: list,
    );
  }
}
```